# Access all defined loggers with logging library in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have several libraries which use the logging library. I want to access all loggers defined in those libraries and set the logging level i want without touching the code of those libraries. I need to that dynamically because i don't know in advance the loggers those libraries will define

How would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logger classes defined are stored in `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict`.